# Is it possible to make a copy of a document daily and include data from the previous day's copy?

Tags: google-apps-script

**I have virtually no coding experience and just started learning how to use Google Apps Script a couple weeks ago for work purposes.**

Background: I created a function that is triggered to make a copy of a template Google Sheet document every morning. This document is designed to be a shift report for a convenience store, which will consist of the day's sales totals and other important information. At the end of each business day, my employees will edit the new copy of this template that was made in the morning with the numbers from that business day.

Here is my goal: I want some of the inventory data from the previous day's copy to appear in the new day's copy, and of course this should be repeated every day. This is because the employees will record the inventory count of certain items, like cigarettes, at the end of the day, which I want to appear as the inventory count at the start of the day on the next day's shift report. I am struggling to figure out how to reference the previous day's copy and get values from it in the same function that creates a new copy. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you haven't done yet, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, make your question about an specific programming issue, show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Hi!, Why don't you use a Google Forms for that? The employees can fill the form, and the data it's send to a main sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PropertiesService to save the name of latest sheet and after use it to create a copy.

```
let properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

function saveLatestSheet(sheetName) {
  properties.setProperty('latestSheet', sheetName);
}

function getLatestSheet() {
  return properties.getProperty('latestSheet');
}
```

I do not know how your code is structed. So, I assume you would use it like this:

```
function createNewSheet() {
 let destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("your_drive_folder_id"); 
 DriveApp.getFileById(getLatestSheet()).makeCopy("name_of_the_new_sheet", destFolder);
 saveLatestSheet("name_of_the_new_sheet");
}
```